# Group Concat Returns Duplicate Entries when applied on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have a problem similar to [Getting data from multiple tables into single row while concatenating some values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938272/getting-data-from-multiple-tables-into-single-row-while-concatenating-some-value) but i am not able to understand it and i am a newbie is sql queries. I have few tables and i have to join them and get some concatenated data in a row. Description is as followings:

```
Table 1 - tasks(id,title,user_id)
id     title          user_id     tree_id
--     -----          -------     -------
1      test task         1          20

Table 2 - task_follower(id,user_id,task_id)
id     user_id   task_id
--     -------   -------
1        1          1

Table 3 - account_user(id,name,email)
id      name    email
--      ----    -----
1       rakesh  kumar3180@gmail.com

Table 2 - category(id,category)
id     category
--     ------- 
1        Project1

Table 2 - task_category(id,user_id,task_id)
id     task_id   category_id
--     -------   -------
1        1          1
```

And the query i run is:

```
    SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name SEPARATOR ',') AS member_names, GROUP_CONCAT(b.email SEPARATOR ',') AS member_emails, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.category) SEPARATOR ',') AS categories FROM tasks AS a INNER JOIN task_followers AS c ON a.id = c.task_id INNER JOIN account_user AS b ON c.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN task_category AS i ON a.id = i.task_id INNER JOIN category AS d ON i.category_id = d.id WHERE a.id = 1 AND a.user_id = 1 AND GROUP BY a.id
```

As the result of this query i get:

```
id    title       user_id   tree_id     member_names    member_emails
---   -----       -------   -------     -------------   -------------
1     test task      1        20        rakesh,rakesh   kumar3180@gmail.com,kumar3180@gmail.com
```

I am not able to understand why name and email is duplicated? Please help me to solve this problem and also if you could explain me where i went wrong conceptually?

I noticed that When the number of category associated with the task is more than one then this problem occurs. Please have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b96eb/1
I have created an example there to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the duplicate using `DISTINCT`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.name SEPARATOR ',')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b96eb/3)

the reason for having duplicate values is because it happens that one of the records from the one table has multiple matches on the other table. [see here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b96eb/4)

Comment: I got your point but there is a problem in this.. Lets say if two users have same name then it will not show both users.. I have edited the example [See Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75d3/1)

Comment: to make long story short, can you show your desired result based on your records above?

Comment: Basically result is same as the fiddle output except these duplicate names and emails... I want all tasks, associated followers(comma separated) and categories(comma separated)...